# How can i send HTTP requests and recieve responses using a DLL?

Tags: dll, curl, httpwebrequest, metatrader5

i am a [metatrader](http://www.metaquotes.net/) developer. it has it's own script language which is similar to C in syntax. one of it's most advantages is that it let you `include` some dll and use it's functions.

now, i want to **send and receive HTTP requests**. which DLL should i use and how?

in PHP context i always use **cURL** library. does it have any DLL that could be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey buddy!
I think you can use something like [this](http://www.forexmq4.blogspot.com) (I didn't check it!) that I found at this forum(www.forex-tsd.com/metatrader-4/11409-mt4-api-3.html)

also I found some helpful techniques here(globaleconomicstrategies.com/index.php/global/global-technology/virtual-private-server-vps-with-web-interface-for-metatrader-forex/) and here(becomewebhost.com/virtual-private-server-vps-with-web-interface-for-metatrader-1040.html) for web based metatrader programming (using VPS's!) I think they may help you and solve your problem directly...

in other hand this(www.alpari-forex.com/en/help/metatrader/) seems a good and useful API but I have no experience and study on it!

hope you success.

P.S :
sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and it don't rely enough on me to allow me post more than just one hyperlink, excuse me for them...

Answer (score 1):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)?

Comment: i knew libcurl... may you explain more? which dll? what are function names? any manual?

Comment: The website includes a download page with Windows DLLs, an API reference for function names and various other documentation. The tutorial explains the "simple" API: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html